# How to import this csv file into R without first column becoming character (I want it to be numeric)?

Tags: r, database, import, data-science

I'm trying to import a csv file into R like this:

```
    # read in data
data <-  read.table('TRY1.csv', header=T, sep = ';', dec = ',', stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
newdata <- na.omit(data) #to omit NA from data
P <- newdata[,1] #imports prices 
Y <- newdata[,2] #imports dividends
G <- newdata[,18] #imports growth rate real cash flows
Yield <- newdata[,17] #imports cash flow yield using dividendsI have added these
```

I haver added `sep = ';', dec = ',', stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to make sure the variables aren't imported as characters but as numbers. These suggestions came from stack. However, it doesn't seem to work for my first column and so P is still imported into R as characters. This is a problem because for my code to work the data has to be numeric. 
**How to fix this? Any help is appreciated.**

Note; using as.numeric() does not help but only gives NA.

Comment: Try adding `, colClasses = "numeric"` to you `read.csv2` statement. This will force every column to be numeric. It won't work if you have other character columns.

Comment: Thanks. At first this didn't work and I got an R error but then I found out my first column contained two dots to mark a 1000. I removed these and the problem was fixed!